# UITextView with an NSAttributedString - attributes are not applied

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Here's what I'm doing:

```
UITextView * myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:defaultFrame];
myTextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"" attributes:defaultAttributeDictionary];
```

No attributes are applied, as can be seen when the user taps on this to edit.

### However:

If I change this to init with a non blank string, eg @"Hi", the attributes are applied, and stick after the user edits the text view. In fact, even if backspace is pressed until the text view is blank, the keyboard dismissed, and then the keyboard reactivated - this still results in the attributed text styling being applied.

### So:

How can I fix this - I'm not sure what's different between the text field between setting @"" as the string and backspacing until the string is @"" and then re editing. Either the reason it's happening and a solution, or a workaround is fine by me!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `attributedText` property to an empty string, try setting the `typingAttributes` property with your `defaultAttributeDictionary`.

```
UITextView * myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:defaultFrame];
myTextView.typingAttributes = defaultAttributeDictionary;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't change the behaviour.